# R Shiny plotly displaying only the latest input from a multiple selection, not all

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to create a Shiny app that uses plotly to create line plots of a number of groups within a single plot. The groups are selected through a multiple selection input.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selected_group", "Filter by group", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  plotlyOutput("plotly_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  archive <- read.csv("archive.csv") %>% group_by(group.id)
  
  selected_archive <- reactive({
    archive %>% filter(group.name %in% input$selected_group)
  })

  observe({
    group_choices <- sort(unique(archive$group.name))
    updateSelectInput(session, "selected_group", choices = group_choices)
  })

  output$archive_lineplot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly()
    group_data_list <- selected_archive() %>% group_split()
    for(group_data in group_data_list){
      p <- add_trace(
        p,
        x = ~group_data$year,
        y = ~group_data$value,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = unique(group_data$group.name)
      )
    }
    p <- layout(
      p,
      title = "Value Over Time",
      xaxis = list(title = "Year"),
      yaxis = list(title = "Value")
    )
    p
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I initially expected that the for loop inside the renderPlotly function would add a trace for each selected group from the multiple selection input. I expected to see a line plot for each group, each with a different color, all displayed in a single plot. This is the typical behavior of add_trace when adding multiple traces in a loop.

However, when I run the app and select multiple groups, the plot only displays the line for the most recently selected group. No traces of previously selected groups appear in the plot, even though they are still selected in the input.

[Plotly only showing the latest selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZNRH.png)

I've tried troubleshooting by making sure the multiple selection input is working correctly, and it is: the input$selected_group variable does contain all selected groups. Therefore, I suspect the problem lies in how I'm using the reactive function or how the reactive dataframe is being handled within the loop.

I'm looking for a solution that correctly creates a line plot for each selected group on a single plot whenever a new selection is made. Thank you!